# Castle.Windsor for ASP.NET Web API tutorial

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api

My searches have yet to turn up a decent tutorial re how to implement Castle.Windsor for ASP.NET Web API ( IHttpController instead of IController ) ...

There are a few blogs that discuss the topic , but these require an expert-level understanding of DI & Windsor.

Does anyone know of a tutorial on the subject that can be followed by someone relatively new to DI & Windsor ?

Something similar to the Windsor tutorial for MVC3 :

http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-one-getting-Windsor.ashx

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the code from *WebApiContrib*, and dig into that. You can find the **Castle Windsor** part [here](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/tree/rc/src/WebApiContrib.IoC.CastleWindsor)

Not much of a tutorial though, as it gives you the entire code, but it might help :)

Comment: The linked implementation is IMO buggy.

Comment: I'm concerned about the usage of IDependencyResolver: that does not provide an hook for releasing component...